# how to find and replace content in an xml file

Tags: shell, replace, xmlhttprequest, find

Trying to find and replace content in xml file

I am running nmap against various hosts and getting an xml output for each run (this is happening in pipeline)
I am merging the xml files for each run into a merged xml

the above is to provide background only..

**My actual issue is:**

I want to replace some content in the merged xml file

I tried **sed -i -e** but it works only for third line where I am trying to change the link but second line is not working, probably due to spaces in the line

I have test.xml file in which I need to replace some content

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<!DOCTYPE nmaprun PUBLIC "-//IDN nmap.org//DTD Nmap XML 1.04//EN" "https://svn.nmap.org/nmap/docs/nmap.dtd"> 
<?xml-stylesheet href="https://svn.nmap.org/nmap/docs/nmap.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
```

In the second line I want to remove content after nmaprun (Remove ' PUBLIC........ until .. .dtd") > should stay

after replace it should be like this

```
<!DOCTYPE nmaprun>
```

and the third line I want to replace `https://svn.nmap.org/nmap/docs/nmap.xsl`
with `file:///usr/local/bin/../share/nmap/nmap.xsl`

after replace it should be displayed as

```
<?xml-stylesheet href="file:///usr/local/bin/../share/nmap/nmap.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
```

after two lines replace it should display as

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
    <!DOCTYPE nmaprun> 
    <?xml-stylesheet href="file:///usr/local/bin/../share/nmap/nmap.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
```

Comment: you can use # instead of / in sed to avoid escaping actual '/'.

Comment: I tried ~, +, #, it worked for the third line (I am guessing its because no spaces in the content to be replaced). It did not work for the second line where there are spaces. Is there a way to escape spaces? (I mean if that is the issue here)

Comment: Yes you can escape spaces with \

Answer (score 0):

Using the below perl one-liner may be useful in your case :

```
perl -pi -w -e 's/search_string/replace_string/g;' a_file
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried the below and it worked without any issues

```
sed -i s~https://svn.nmap.org/nmap/docs/nmap.xsl~file:///usr/bin/../share/nmap/nmap.xsl~g' nmap_merge.xml



sed -i 's~!DOCTYPE nmaprun PUBLIC "-//IDN nmap.org//DTD Nmap XML 1.04//EN" "https://svn.nmap.org/nmap/docs/nmap.dtd"~!DOCTYPE nmaprun~g' nmap_merge.xml
```